# Can i still use gapi with google identity services and the authorization code flow?

Tags: javascript, google-api

I've been trying to implement the new Google Identity Services (GIS) and its authorization code flow to a javascript webapp i'm developing that should sign in a user with its google account and allow me to do some operation on its Google Drive. I've implemented my backend methods, storing refresh token, etc.

According to [the documentation about "the new way" of doing things for the implicit flow](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/migration-to-gis#the_new_way), if you select the GAPI callback tab, a comment will tell you in a comment at some point :

> GIS has automatically updated gapi.client with the newly issued access token.

whick makes sense, since we're getting the token using this GIS, so now they're able to keep using the old gapi (to fetch calendar events here). But for [the authorization code flow](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/migration-to-gis#the_new_way_2), it seems that there is now way to pass the access_token to gapi in order to do the same thing. Using `gapi.client.setToken` throws an error saying that it is deprecated.

Is there a way to keep using gapi with this flow and GIS ?

Comment: Signin and authorization are two different things.

Comment: @DalmTo you're not answering the question

Comment: Well, you know your right.   Let me know if my answer helps at all.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is what you are doing is two diffrent things.  In the old library Authentication and authorization were a single thing.  They have split it with the new library.

Sign-in (open id connect) or authentication is the act of a user logging into your application with their google account.  This returns to you and id token granting you access to see the user profile information [Sign in with Google demo](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview)  Think of this as your birth certificate.  It verifies that the user behind the machine is the user who owns the account.

Oauth2 or authorization is a completely different concept.  With authorization you are asking a user to grant your application permission to access their data.  [Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2).

You will need to first authencation the user then request that they authorize your application access their data.  Its going to be two steps.

Comment: I've understood those principles. My question is not about that actually. Using the new signin/auth library, how can i inject my access token (post authorization) to the google-api-javascript-client (https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client) ? I know it says in the doc that the auth section is deprecated, i was wondering if you could somehow use this as a sdk instead of calling the google apis urls directly through axios